# How to manipulate the initial conditions in a ODE system?

Tags: manipulate, dynamic

```
Cinetica2 = ({
    {0, 0.04, 16.04, 0.30},
    {2, 0.19, 13.52, 0.51},
    {4, 0.39, 10.99, 1.22},
    {6, 1.11, 8.23, 2.96},
    {8, 1.96, 0.37, 6.08},
    {10, 2.09, 0.31, 5.82},
    {12, 2.41, 0.28, 5.69},
    {14, 2.41, 0.26, 5.62}
   });

DataX = {{0, 0.04}, {2, 0.19}, {4, 0.39}, {6, 1.11}, {8, 1.96}, {10, 
    2.09}, {12, 2.41}, {14, 2.41}};
DataS = {{0, 16.04}, {2, 13.52}, {4, 10.99}, {6, 8.23}, {8, 
    0.37}, {10, 0.31}, {12, 0.28}, {14, 0.26}};
DataEta = {{0, 0.30}, {2, 0.51}, {4, 1.22}, {6, 2.96}, {8, 6.08}, {10,
     5.82}, {12, 5.69}, {14, 5.62}};

Manipulate[Module[{Gompertz, Ks, Yxsg, Ypsg, Yps, Ms, Yo2, Coe},
  Ks = 0.025; Yxsg = 0.44; Ypsg = 0.10; Yps = 0.4; Ms = 0.036; 
  Yo2 = 1.14; Coe = 0.007;
  μv = μmax Su[t]/(Ks + Su[t])*(Cox[t]/(ko + Cox[t]));
  Rb1 = (μv*Log[Kx/Yb[t]]*Yb[t]);
  REt1 = α*Rb1 + β*Yb[t];
  RPr1 = αα*Rb1 + ββ*Yb[t];
  Gompertz = NDSolve[{D[Yb[t], {t, 1}] == (μv*Log[Kx/Yb[t]]*Yb[t]),
     D[Su[t], {t, 1}] == -(Rb1/Yxsg) - Ms Yb[t] - REt1/Ypsg - RPr1/Yps,
     D[Pro[t], {t, 1}] == RPr1,
     D[Eta[t], {t, 1}] == REt1,
     D[Cox[t], {t, 1}] == KlA*(Coe - Cox[t]) - (μv/Yo2)*Yb[t],
     Yb[0] == 0.1, Su[0] == 15, Pro[0] == 0.01, Eta[0] == 0.36, 
     Cox[0] == 0.007},
    {Yb[t], Su[t], Pro[t], Eta[t], Cox[t]}, {t, 0, 15}];
  Multicolumn[{
    Show[Plot[Evaluate[Yb[t] /. Gompertz], {t, 0, 15}, 
      PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}, 
      FrameLabel -> {"time (h)", "Concentration(g/L)"}, 
      PlotLabel -> "Biomass Production", PlotLegends -> {"[Biomass]"},
       PlotTheme -> "Scientific", GridLines -> Automatic, 
      ImageSize -> Small], 
     ListPlot[DataX, Filling -> Axis, 
      PlotMarkers -> Style["\[FilledCircle]", 12, Blue], 
      PlotStyle -> Red, PlotLegends -> {"Experimental data"}]],
    Show[Plot[Evaluate[Su[t] /. Gompertz], {t, 0, 15}, 
      PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {Orange, Thick}, 
      FrameLabel -> {"time (h)", "Concentration(g/L)"}, 
      PlotLabel -> "Substrate Uptake", PlotLegends -> {"[Substrate]"},
       PlotTheme -> "Scientific", GridLines -> Automatic, 
      ImageSize -> Small], 
     ListPlot[DataS, Filling -> Axis, 
      PlotMarkers -> Style["\[FilledCircle]", 12, Orange], 
      PlotStyle -> Red, PlotLegends -> {"Experimental data"}]],
    Show[Plot[Evaluate[Eta[t] /. Gompertz], {t, 0, 15}, 
      PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {Gray, Thick}, 
      FrameLabel -> {"time (h)", "Concentration(g/L)"}, 
      PlotLabel -> "Ethanol Formation", PlotLegends -> {"[Ethanol]"}, 
      PlotTheme -> "Scientific", GridLines -> Automatic, 
      ImageSize -> Small], 
     ListPlot[DataEta, Filling -> Axis, 
      PlotMarkers -> Style["\[FilledCircle]", 12, Black], 
      PlotStyle -> Black, PlotLegends -> {"Experimental data"}]],
    Plot[Evaluate[{α* μv + β} /. Gompertz], {t, 0, 
      15}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
     PlotStyle -> {Gray, Thick}, 
     FrameLabel -> {"time (h)", "Concentration(g/L)"}, 
     PlotLabel -> "qp", PlotLegends -> {"qp"}, 
     PlotTheme -> "Scientific", GridLines -> Automatic, 
     ImageSize -> Small], 2}]],
 Item[Style["Metaboites Formation", Bold, Blue, Italic, 12], 
  Alignment -> Center],
 Item[Style["Ethanol", Bold], Alignment -> Center],
 {{α, 0.25, "alfa"}, 0, 1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Open"},
 {{β, 0.01, "beta"}, 0, 1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Open"},
 Item[Style["Product", Bold], Alignment -> Center],
 {{αα, 0.01, "alfa"}, 0, 1, 0.01, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{ββ, 0.01, "beta"}, 0, 1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 Delimiter, 
 Item[Style["oxygen transfer coefficient", Bold], Alignment -> Center],
 {{KlA, 450, "Kla"}, 0, 500, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 Delimiter, Item[Style["Growth rate", Bold], Alignment -> Center],
 {{μmax, 0.9, "μmax"}, 0.05, 1, 0.05, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 Delimiter, 
 Item[Style["Constant oxygen affinity", Bold], Alignment -> Center],
 {{ko, 0.021, "kc"}, 0, 0.03, 0.001, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 Delimiter, 
 Item[Style["Gompertz Model", Bold, Blue, Italic, 12], 
  Alignment -> Left],
 Item[Style["Maximum biomass concentration", Bold], 
  Alignment -> Center],
 {{Kx, 3, "K"}, 1, 3.5, 0.5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {α, β, αα, β\
 β, μmax, ko, Kx, KlA}, SynchronousUpdating -> False, 
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

Comment: Hi, everybody, I would like to manipulate the initial values for the five diffrential equations like i did with the parameters, but I could not find a good way for do it, any idea?, thankyou.

Comment: Hi,I would like to manipulate the initial values for the five diffrential equations like i did with the parameters, it means: I have this: I would like to manipulate the initial values like I did with the parameters, but really I do not Know how. I mean, actually I have this: Yb[0] == 0.1, Su[0] == 15, Pro[0] == 0.01, Eta[0] == 0.36, Cox[0] == 0.007 but I want to chance dinamically this values like: Yb[0] == Yb0, Su[0] == Su0, Pro[0] == Pro0, Eta[0] == Eta0, Cox[0] == Cox0

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 1):

Changing initial conditions can be accomplished in the same way that parameters are changed.  For instance, replace `Yb[0] == 0.1` by `Yb[0] == Yb0`, add the corresponding control,

```
{{Yb0, 0.1}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
```

and include `Yb0` in the list of `TrackedSymbols`.